# Mongoose "find" on mutilple fields with one query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm making an api with nodejs/express/mongoDB on a product that can be founded on the market. For each product I have a title, a brand, an image, a quantity...

We want that the user can make a research with the title and the brand in the same query and that the api returns the product that matches with the query.

For now I try with $regex, $in, $and, $or, $gte, $lte... but I don't find the combination.

```
const query = req.params.query.replace(/_/g, ' ');
Product.find({
    $and: [{
        title: query
    },
    {
        brand: query
    }]
})
.then()
.catch()
```

Thanks for your answers!

**EDIT**

Here is an example to help the comprehension.

My table :
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Nbq.png)

Example of user's query :

- "phone" : return all the products that contain phone in their title
- "apple" : return all the products that contain Apple in their brand
- "apple phone" : return all the products that contain Apple in their brand and phone in their title

I hope this example will help...

Comment: Do you get an error with `Product.find({title:'test', brand:'test'})` ? I guess you can use multiple query field on find method. Or didn't i understand the question ?

Comment: @Halil For exemple, in my database I have many Iphone (X, XR, 11, 12...) and for everyone the brand is Apple. When a user makes the query "Iphone XR Apple" I want that the api return all the information about the Iphone XR. If y make `Product.find({title:'Iphone XR Apple', brand:'Iphone XR Apple'})` it will returns nothing because nothing as "Iphone XR Apple" for title or brand. Do you understand ?

Comment: I understand. If your query text is known you can make it easily. For example as you said query text is "Iphone XR Apple". Do you split it like "Iphone XR" and "Apple" ? Then you can make a query with a brand and a title. There is an important mandatory. Incoming text have to be known structure. Can you use like that ? I don't be make sure

Comment: I already think about this solution, but the query can also be "Apple iPhone XR"... The query is made by the users and I can (and don't want) control it. I think the solution is on the mongoose's filters not on the treatment of the query.

Answer (score 0):

I previously had the same requirement and the below snippet helped me find the query-matched results from the database collection.
One more thing is, you are finding the value of `req.params.query` conform wether it's the same or not.

if you pass in query like : `/?query=book` then in the API, you can get it as `req.query,query`
and if you pass the data as `/book` and if you are reading the query some thing like this, `/:query` then use `req.params.query`

considering that your `req.params.query` has a valid value, look at this one:

```
const key = new RegExp(req.params.query, 'i');
Product.find({$or : [{ "title" : key }, { "brand" : key }]})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Feel free to comment if you are stuck with something here or not getting a portion of it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This filter works only if the user made a request with just the title or just the brand, not with the title AND the brand (in this case it returns nothing). I want that if the user makes the request "phone Apple" it returns all the Apple's phones (those who had "phone" in their title and "Apple" in their brand).

Comment: In that case just change **$or** with **$and** or just use 
    find({ title, brand })

Comment: Its can't work because if make the request "Apple phone", nothing has for title "Apple phone" and nothing as for brand "Apple phone". Do you understand the problem ?